# Assigning variables within the ifelse function in r

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I am pretty new to r and I am trying to get a better grasp of this language by solving problems from one of the books about r (I am not sure if I can put the title here to not advertise it). One of the problems is asking for conditional assigning values to variables, based on certain criteria. To be more precise, I am randomly choosing a number between 2 and 12 (throwing 2 dice) and dependently on the value I get, I have to assign values to variables `status` and `points` as follows:

1. if score is 2,3, or 12 then `status <- FALSE` and `points <- NA`
2. if score is 7 or 11 then `status <- TRUE` and `points <- NA`
3. if score is 4-6,8-10 then `status <- NA` and `points <- score`

It is quite simple problem and I know that the following code works:

```
score <- sample(2:12,1)
    if(score %in% c(2,3,12)){
        status <- FALSE
        points <- NA
    } else if(score %in% c(7,11)){
        status <- TRUE
        points <- NA
    } else {
        status <- NA
        points <- score
    }
```

I was also trying to solve this problem using the `ifelse` function but I get an error when I try to assign variables. Here is what I did (I know that what I get right now is a character vector but that was the only way I could make it work).

```
ifelse(any(score == c(2,3,12)), "game_status = FALSE, point = NA", 
       ifelse(any(score == c(7,11)), "game_status = TRUE, point = NA", 
       paste("game_status = NA, point = ", score)))
```

Is there a way to assign values within the `ifelse` function? Also, can it be done with the `switch` function? I am trying to figure out if there is more than just one way to solve this simple problem so that I know how to proceed with more complicated ones.

Thank you!

Comment: `ifelse` is a function. `if` and `else` are control statements. `ifelse` is meant to have a single (possibly vector) return value. It's not really designed to do what you're trying to make it do.

Comment: `ifelse` should be assigned to something like: `example<-ifelse(...)`, so you can not assign values within it.

Comment: This question needs to be re-written. `ifelse` vs `if-else` and assignment vs variable values. `loops` tag also needs to be removed.

Comment: Thank you! It makes much more sense now. There is a lot I still need to learn.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant answer but you could do this which demonstrates use of `ifelse` as well as conditional statements:

```
status=NULL
status[score %in% c(2,3,12)]<-FALSE
status[score %in% c(7,11)]<-TRUE
status[score %in% c(4:6,8:10)]<-NA

points=ifelse(score %in% c(4:6,8:10),score,NA)
```

As you can see, I used `ifelse` to create a logical statement for `points` the first argument is the logical test, the second argument replaces the value of score if true and the last replaces the value if false.